# How do you deal with the hight heat of propane?

Tags: temperature, propane-cooktop

I have only cooked with natural gas in the past and now have a propane stove.

I find that it burns very hot and it is difficult to control the heat.

I have it turned down to the minimum, almost flickering out, and have stacked a second trestle iron below the pan and it is still difficult to manage the heat.

What can I do?

The cooktop looks similar, but not exactly like this:

[image]

Comment: Is the stove designed for propane or natural gas?  It sounds like it might not have been converted (where you restrict the amount of gas that gets through to the burner).  And make sure to convert the oven, too ... there are lots of stories about huge flames in ovens because people forgot that part

Comment: @Joe How can I tell? The cooktop has no model number at all or identification plate. It just says "Viking Professional" and that is it. There is no obvious way to lift the top plate to see the regulator.

Comment: I found a [manual on how to do the conversion to propane](http://www.vikingrange.com/MEDIA_CustomProductCatalog/m5730387_F20953_EN.pdf), but the most obvious part to check would require removing a part that if you didn't close it back up correctly could cause a fuel leak & explosion.  You might be able to check the orafices, and see if they match up with the numbers in the guide as I think that just requires lifting the burner cap and head.  I would avoid unscrewing anything

Comment: @Joe Removing the cooktop looks problematic because it is of the "sealed" type. I was able to unscrew one of the burner caps and get access to the brass orifice. I tested the orifice with pin gages and it was between 0.043" and 0.044" which I think is a normal range for propane.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this might be to get a heat diffuser - this is basically a metal disc with holes in it that moderates the temperature by only letting some of the direct heat pass through. These sometimes come with handles so that you can move them on/off the element while cooking.

google: `gas stove heat diffuser` for options in your region. In the US I can get them for about $5-10

Comment: Other options for Googling would be as a deflector or under a specific name such as Heat Master Flame Tamer for more options.  They all work about the same, just more options.  Another approach would be to use a double boiler to tame things down which may be a quick option if you do not think the shields will fit as you like or work for you..